# Essential Business System licensing grace period

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing, amazon-ebs, windows-server-essentials

After our initial installation and configuring we are ready to migrate users over to our EBS domain.  We have installed enough device CALs to cover the organization however they must be assigned to the device manually before users can log into their computers.

Is there a way to reset the 30 compliance grace period so we can join all the computers at once then go aback and assign the CALs?  If not can we configure EBS to assign one of the available Device CALs to new computers as they joint the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**slmgr -rearm** does not reset client licensing.

You can reset the grace period for activation for the servers, but once the initial 30 days are up the CAL enforcement is enabled and cannot be prolonged.

In regards to your question about assigning CALs automatically to devices. I am not sure if it could be done automatically, but you can use the script mentioned in the Blog Post link below. However I think that it is for bulk assigning CALs to users and not devices. But it could put you on the correct path.

[Link to Blog Post](http://blogs.technet.com/essentialbusinessserver/archive/2009/10/12/understanding-ebs-client-licensing.aspx)